# Firebase Admin SDK FirebaseAuthException : Unexpected error refreshing access token

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Admin SDK to get registered users to my Spring boot app this worked fine previous days ago

```java
UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance()).getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

But suddenly  I'm receiving this `FirbaseAuthExcetpion`

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Unknown error while making a remote service call: Unexpected error refreshing access token
```

Can you help me with this exception.
Thank you

Comment: This is GitHub issue I raised https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/629

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was a dependency conflict of `com.google.guava` library, in my case Swagger has been using old a version of Guava, so I had to add exclusion for Swagger Guava library

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: In my case I had to update guava to latest version, also remove version tag from `<Properties>` and add `<Version>`  directly below  `<artifactId>` . for some reason it didnt read version from properties